# How to Increase the Vocal Range of my Chest voice without using Mixed Voice

Tags: voice

I understand that normally there is a transition state between chest and head voice called mixed voice when you are trying to sing higher notes.

So my chest voice currently caps off at F4 and I would really love to hit G4 comfortably while ONLY using chest voice. Is this possible? If so, what type of exercises should I pursue in order to reach my goal?

Thanks

Comment: I've been trying to do this too but I hit I guess a wall, no progress happening for the last few months so I'm just going to bite the bullet and take lessons. You could try that as well

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible to increase your chest voice range, I've done so.  I had to study with a voice teacher to do this.  I can tell you that I was instructed to use lip rolls first, then "mum"'s (mum's are where you sing pitches uses the word "mum" ) to accomplish this.    I'm a second bass, and when I started I could hit middle "C" IF I was lucky, know, "F#" above middle "C" is pretty easy,  "G" above middle "C" requires a  good warmup  - although I definitely recommend singing in mix because it's easier to transition to head voice that way.   Check out Brett Manning - he's who I learned from !

Answer (score 0):

You should sing comfortably in ALL YOUR RANGE. Your goal shouldn't only be hitting a G4, but to acquire the technique that allows you to sing comfortably. This means that potentially you could sing higher notes. But that's not because you exercised to increase your vocal range. It's because the technique allows you to be more relaxed and use the correct muscles when you approach certain notes.

Always use your resonance mask when you sing, and don't create artificial tension, which is probably the cause of your wall at F4. Try to search that resonance mask and a "twang" (

) and see if you can imitate a siren as high as you can without going to head voice. If you can reach a G4 doing the siren exercise, you should be able to sing a G4 comfortably.

Comment: I'm not sure this directly answers the question. The OP is asking specifically about increasing the range of *chest voice*, not about increasing range in general.

Comment: See my last recommendation about the siren exercise. I mean doing it without going to head voice, that way you can have an idea of how your chest voice is increasing. It's just an exercise meant to produce a sound without any artificial tension, and experiment and feel new sensations in your throat.